# Slow query on remote database

Tags: php, sql, adodb, freetds

I have:

- A linux server with PHP 5.3.2 and Apache 2.0
- A windows Server with SQL SERVER

I connect my linux server with database with unixODBC 2.3.1 and FREETDS 0.9.1

The connection is okay but the queries are slow.
Here is my code that generate the image below:

```
$this->adodb->LogSQL(true); // turn on logging
$query = "select c.name, t.name, c.length from syscolumns c join systypes t on t.xusertype = c.xusertype
          join sysobjects o on o.id=c.id where o.name = 'CONDOMINIO'";
$res = $this->adodb->Execute($query);
$this->adodb->LogSQL(false); // turn off logging
$perf = NewPerfMonitor($this->adodb);
echo $perf->SuspiciousSQL();
echo $perf->ExpensiveSQL();
```

[Image http://www.vigoonline.net/slow.png](http://www.vigoonline.net/slow.png)

As you can see, the first query has an average time of 4.68 seconds, which is way too slow.

If I execute the same query like this:

```
$this->adodb->_query($query);
```

Then the time to execute the query takes less than a second what is great. Has anyone else experienced the same thing?

The query called with "Execute" is used for the own class for bringing the "MetaColumns" information from the table

The table "CONDOMINIO" only has 21 rows.

If the server database is in the same machine with the application script, then the response is fast!

Comment: I know it's traditional to put SQL query keywords in all caps, but that doesn't mean your title has to be all caps too.

Comment: Are you confident the problem is _this_ query? Perhaps the initial connection or first query is always going to be slow..?

Comment: Yes because if i execute with the method "_query" from ADODB , the query is executed really fast...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this myself.
Here is what I did:

Go to the file `/adodb/drivers/adodb-odbc.inc.php` and to the class `ADODB_odbc`

Here try to find:

```
var $curmode = SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER
```

and change it to:

```
var $curmode = SQL_CUR_USE_IF_NEEDED;
```

This will make the connection use `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` when needed and "Voila" DB access speed to SQL server is really fast!